# Returning a reference to an object owned by a data structure

Tags: c++

My set:

```
std::set<Object> objects;
```

I want find a object and return it as a reference, also inserting it if it doesn't exist:

```
const Object& get(params...){
    Object obj(params...);
    std::set<Object>::const_iterator i = objects.find(obj);
    if(i != objects.end())
        return *i;
    objects.insert(obj);
    return * objects.find(obj);
}
```

This can result in a segmentation fault or this will work always?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterator invalidation rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you do with the collection.

Insertions and removals from an `std::set` won't invalidate iterators to the other elements of the collection, but if you are going to erase *that* element from the collection, then the iterators and references to it will be invalidated and you might end up with an invalid reference.

Comment: Probably yes (and if you will use pointers, consider using *smart* pointers), but it's hard to say without knowing the logics of your application. I guess it all depends on whether you need reference semantics or not. Maybe [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539624/memory-management-patterns-in-c/14539873#14539873) will help delucidating

Comment: Actually smart pointers would not be appropriate really, since there would be no ownership going on with the pointer being returned. Unless you want to make the whole container contain `shared_ptr` or something.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: That's what I meant. The container would be a `set<shared_ptr<T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Not this code by itself. But you might erase an object and still attempt to use its reference later

Answer (score 0):

I strongly discourage this policy also if you don't plan to use erase, a modification in future could lead to nasty bugs.

If your object is small enough return it by copy.

If the object is quite big maybe you can use a boost smart pointer  to avoid segmentation fault.