# What is value type of *T?

Tags: c++11

Let's consider very short piece of code in C++:

```
class T{
};
T *t = new T();
```

What is type of `*t`? rvalue/lvalue/xvalue/glvalue? why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't follow. Are you asking what the type of the *expression* `*t` is? Or are you asking what the type of the *variable* `t` is?

Comment: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40169699/3521116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check for *lvalue* is very simple. Can it appear on the left hand side of an assignment operator?

In your case, the answer is "yes".

```
*t = T();
```

is valid. Hence, the value of type of `*t` is *lvalue*.

By virtue of being an *lvalue*, it is also a *glvalue*.

From https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.lval:

> A glvalue (“generalized” lvalue) is an lvalue or an xvalue.

Comment: It's also a glvalue.

Comment: Well, overloading `operator =` for `T` would make it able to be called with an rvalue, too, so this check is not really accurate.

Comment: @Quentin, true. I am sure the OP is not looking at anything that deep.

Comment: @RSahu I wrote too fast. It actually does that even without overloading (which, in restrospect, is obvious)... So `struct Foo { }; Foo{} = Foo{};` compiles just fine.

Comment: @Quentin, by strict definition of the standards, an lvalue *designates a function or an object*. It doesn't say anything about the life time of the object. If we go by that imprecise definition, even a temporary object, which does designate an object, should qualify as an lvalue.