# Conditions for entering to destructor

Tags: c++

I have function I wrote in some class.
I don't understand why when I create object named: Square square; a d'tor of Square is being called when exiting the function.
While when I create the object as: Square* square = new Square(); no d'tor is being called.

**There is no inheritance at all on the classes**.

Here an example for the function in a two versions:

```
//=======Enter to d'tor in the end of the function to ~Square==========
void DrawShapesApp::addSquare()
{
    int row, col;
    int edge;
    char ch;

    Square square;

    getSquareInfo(row, col, edge, ch);
    square.setAll(row, col, edge, ch);
    m_squares.push_back(&square);
}





//=======Doesn't enter to d'tor in the end of the function==========
void DrawShapesApp::addSquare()
{
    int row, col;
    int edge;
    char ch;
    Square* square = new Square();

    getSquareInfo(row, col, edge, ch);
        (*square).setAll(row, col, edge, ch);
    m_squares.push_back(&square);
}
```

Comment: You tagged this as C#,C++ and C. I'm assuming this is a C++ problem from the syntax?

Comment: If you only change `vector<Square*> m_squares;` to `vector<Square> m_squares;` then all your problems will go away. Don't use pointers, especially not in STL classes.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an object with "new", *you* are responsible for deleting it. This is done with "delete":

```
delete square;
```

In your second function you have a memory leak -- the object is never destroyed and the memory is never freed.

Comment: .. One could say using "new" is a heap of problems

Answer (score 1):

```
Square* square = new Square();
```

This is a definition of a `Square*` with automatic storage duration. That pointer *is* destroyed automatically at the end of the function.

However, the pointer is initialized with the result of `new Square()`. This *new-expression* creates an object of type `Square` with *dynamic storage duration*. That object is *not* destroyed at the end of the function.

To destroy an object with dynamic storage duration, you must call `delete` on a pointer to that object. In this case, do:

```
delete square;
```

If you do not destroy the object manually, you will have a memory leak.

However, it is common in modern C++ to have your dynamically allocated objects managed by a smart pointer that will handle the `delete` for you:

```
std::unique_ptr<Square> square(new Square());
```

Answer (score 1):

An object created this way:

```
Square square;
```

Is said to have **automatic storage duration**, and will be destroyed *automatically* when it goes out of scope. For instance:

```
void foo()
{
    Square square1;
    {
        Square square2;
    } // Here square2 will be destroyed

    if (cond) { /* .... */ }
    else
    {
        Square square3;
        // ...
    } // Here square3 will be destroyed
    // ...
} // Here square1 will be destroyed
```

You usually choose to instantiate objects this way if you do not need/want them to survive the end of their scope (although one could argue that *moving* objects in C++11 provides a way of achieving this also for objects with automatic storage duration).

An object created this way, on the other hand:

```
Square* pSquare = new Square();
```

Is said to have **dynamic storage duration**, and will be destroyed when `delete` will be invoked for a pointer to that object:

```
delete pSquare;
```

In this case, *you* have the responsibility of manually destroying the object, and failing to do so for every object allocated with `new` will cause a *memory leak*. For instance:

```
void foo()
{
    Square* pSquare1 = new Square();
    Square* pSquare2 = nullptr;
    if (/* ... */)
    {
        pSquare2 = new Square();
    }

    delete pSquare2; // Here the object pointed to by pSquare2 is destroyed
} // Whoops! I forgot deleting the object pointed to by pSquare1, that's a leak!
```

You normally choose to create objects this way if you want them to live beyond the end of their scope, and/or if you need [reference semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539624/memory-management-patterns-in-c/14539873#14539873).

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an object like this

```
Square square;
```

It will be destroyed after going out of declaration scope, automatically.

And...

When you declare an object like this

```
Square *square = new Square();
```

It will be destroyed after `delete`. You must explicitly delete the object.