# Memory run time error: where do we delete this pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-leaks

In the four method below, only better is what we should do. We want to dynamic allocation here to avoid a bad function return. But, **where do we delete f?** Delete at the function that calls better()? But there is no f any more in that case.

```
Foo *bad() {
  Foo f;
  return &f;
}

Foo &alsoBad() {
  Foo f;
  return f;
}

Foo mediocre() {
  Foo f;
  return f;
}

Foo * better() {
  Foo *f = new Foo;
  return f;
}
```

Comment: Put it into a smart pointer and return that to make the "better" one work better.

Comment: `mediocre` is actually the best, just saying. See [_Modern C++ Style_](http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1). Also see [_C++11 Style_](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style) where Bjarne Stroustrup discusses move semantics.

Comment: You're basically asking "How do I do memory management", an incredibly broad and subjective topic.

Comment: @Zoidberg is right. Even crustaceans know that manual resource management is crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But there is no f any more in that case.

Well, the pointer `f` goes out of scope, that's true, but we are still returning a pointer to the same object that `f` pointed to.

Therefore, we still have a handle to that object and we still can invoke `delete` on the returned pointer. In fact, you can invoke `delete` *any time* after creating an object with `new`.

What you have to take care is that:

- you do indeed invoke `delete` at some point for each object allocated with `new` (otherwise you have a memory leak);
- you do not call `delete` more than once for the same object, otherwise you get undefined behavior;
- you do not dereference a pointer which points to an object that has been destroyed (i.e. a "dangling pointer"), otherwise you get undefined behavior.

In general, manual memory management through `new` and `delete` is discouraged in Modern C++, and ownership policies should be realized through *smart pointers* instead. **OR...**

> In the four method below, only better is what we should do

**Not exactly**. In fact, I would say we should definitely not do `better()` - although we *could* do a version of `better()` modified to create and return a smart pointer rather than an owning raw pointer.

However, function `mediocre()` is actually pretty good, and that is for two reasons:

1. First of all because it is very likely that the compiler will elide the call to the copy constructor and perform [**(Named) Return Value optimization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), thus resulting in no run-time overhead;
2. Secondly, because thanks to C++11's move semantics, it is possible to
   equip `Foo` with a *move constructor* that makes returning by value
   efficient in most cases even when no elision is performed.

Moreover, as [Zoidberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142019/zoidberg) correctly mentions in the comments, you should not use pointers at all if you do not really need them. Unique ownership can often by realized by creating objects with automatic storage duration (aka "on the stack"), and move semantics makes this practice efficient. Pointers should be created only [*when you need reference semantics*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539624/memory-management-patterns-in-c/14539873#14539873).

Comment: I would add to the last sentence that in many cases ownership can be expressed without any pointers (or references, for that matter) at all.

Comment: @Zoidberg: Absolutely. Will mention that. Thank you

Comment: *you do indeed invoke `delete` at some point to all object allocated with `new`* I will admit this is sometimes not as easy to do as you would think, especially if you have different memory allocators. So the `better` function would have a complement, `betterCallMeWhenYouAreDone` that frees the allocated objects and you have to call it instead of `delete`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: True, but I would rather think of forgetting of `better()` at all, because is actually `quite_bad()` in Modern C++. Manual memory management is superseded by smart pointers (which also support custom deleters), and those are saving us from most of the troubles you are probably thinking of in relation with the part of my answer you quoted.